# Job planification: looking for UI design to make my own

Tags: php, user-interface, extjs

I'm developping an admin panel with ExtJS.

I've almost finished it except one thing: I need the "partner" who logs in to be able to configure when he/she works.

I'm like re-inventing the wheel, but thanks to ExtJS and my structure this won't be a problem.

The actual problem is about UI design:

- I want to make very simple so that it's possible to enter very simple values like "I'm working each working days from 8 to 12 then 14 to 18"
- I want to make it more configurable and be able to precise "I'm on vacation from july,1st until august,31th"
- I want to make it *even more* configurable and be able to precise "the month of january, I'm working every single day from 8 to 20 non-stop".

I was looking for some inspiration with Microsoft Scheduler but to be honest, a basic user will never ever (ever x 87) be able to use such a UI to configure when he/she works

Same for unix cronjob. From my point of view, this is very hard to understand from a basic user's point of view.

So my question is: do you know where I could find some inspiration for this? And maybe if there are some Php components well written out there to handle such things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the way I did it: a "list" of rows that contains:

- start hour
- end hour
- start date
- end date

and a list of associated days.

This way it's possible to configure any kind of scenarii, even though it requires a bit of thinking, because you do not have to enter it a "natural" way (= you usually think first days of week you work, the hours and *maybe* the start/end days = it's the opposite of my configuration).